# Make route png on server side

Tags: openstreetmap

I have to make some route in png file. Instead of send big data array to client I want to make that route on Server side and send png image to client. Which instrument can I use for that taks? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does it necessarily has to be a static PNG image? Otherwise better go for a JavaScript solution using Leaflet or OpenLayers.

Comment: Can I make OpenLayer on server side with just route without map?

Comment: You could use the MiniGraphUI class of GraphHopper which is a very raw and basic street network visualization via Java Swing but can easily produce png files with a route geometry too via Graphics or BufferedImage. But as @scai mentioned: maybe you can get Leaflet working via node.js?

Comment: But maybe you have a different problem. What do you mean with 'big data array'? A routing response shouldn't be big (especially compared to an image)

Comment: @Karussell route may consist of a lot of points. In that case load prepared route from server is preferable.

Comment: Still the route is usually pretty small compared to map tiles. Maybe you try to describe you problem in more details. Currently it is really unclear what you are trying to do.